# Should I use ELSE IF? for better performance?

Tags: if-statement

Newbie here and I just want to know should I use ELSE IF for something like below:

```
(function)
IF x==1
IF x==2
IF x==3
```

That is the way I am using, because the x will not be anything else. However, I think that if the x is equal to 1, the program still gonna run through the following codes (which turn out to be FALSE FALSE FALSE ...). Should I use ELSE IF so it won't have to run the rest? Will that help the performance?

Why don't I want to use ELSE IF? because I'd like each code block (IF x==n) to be similar, **not like this**:

```
IF x==1
ELSE IF x==2
ELSE IF x==3
```

(each ELSE IF block is part of the block above it)

But the program will repeatedly call this function so I am worried about the performance or delay.

Comment: You should also tag your question to indicate the language you're using, but generally, worrying about this kind of thing is what we call "premature optimization" -- if you do attain any performance gains, they're probably irrelevant in nearly all normal programming scenarios. (I do very performance-sensitive game programming and I would never worry about this...)

Comment: Yes, all `IF`s will be checked by compiler because they are separate to each other. `IF-ELSE` will be better, I think... Why don't you use `switch` by the way?

Comment: I think you should be concerned about readability and maintenance for the most part.  Write the code whichever way best expresses your intent and the problem domain, and is least likely to trip up a future maintainer.  Let the compiler worry about optimizing the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** If you do not need to handle a case where multiple conditions might be true at the same time, **always** use

```
if (condition) {
    //do something
}
else if (other_condition) {
    //do something else
}
else { //in all other conditions
    //default behaviour
}
```

**Long answer:**

1. As others have already stated, **performance is not really a big concern**  (unless you are writing production code for enterprise software targeted at colossal businesses). **In case performance** is indeed **crucial** though, you should go for the above format anyway. So that might be a good practice/habit to get used to (especially if you are now starting your code journey)
2. Switch could be an alternative, but since you haven't specified the language I would avoid suggesting it since, in some languages, it defaults to [fall-through](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) (which might get you where you started in the first place and confuse you even more)
3. Performance might not be a concern. But keep in mind that [**logic errors**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error) are a **huge enemy** to programming, and your solution is prone to them if you don't actually **need it to** be able to match more than one cases. Consider the following case.

   ```
   if (x == 1) {
       x = x + 1
   }
   if (x == 2) {
       x = x + 2
   }
   if (x >= 3) {
       print("Error: x should only be 1 or 2!")
   }
   ```

In this case, you would expect that if `x >= 3` you would warn about an **error in value** since you only had in mind handling the values **1** or **2**. Actually though, even if the value of x is **1** or **2** (which you have **considered** to be **valid**) the **same error message would be printed!**. That's because you have allowed the possibility of more than one conditions being checked and the respective code block being executed each time. Note that this is an **oversimplified example**. In times, this can be a great pain! Especially if you collaborate with others and you share the code and you are aiming for expendable and maintainable code.

To conclude, do not use a simpler solution if you haven't thought it through. Go for the complete one instead and take in mind all possible outcomes (usually the **worst case** scenarios and even **future features** and code).

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If the value being tested is expected to be able to match multiple in a single calling, then test each (IF, IF, ...).
If the value is expected to only match one, then check for it and stop if you find it (IF, ELSE IF, ELSE IF...).
If the values are expected to be one of a known set, then go right to it (switch).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is javascript, but this should be about the same for anything else.

The code inside the `if` statement will only be run if the condition you provide it is true. For example, if you declare `x = 1`, we could have something like:

```
function something() {
if(x == 1) {
  //do this
}
if(x == 2) {
  //do that
}
if(x == 3) {
  //do this and that
}
```

The first block would be run and everything else is ignored. An `else-if` statement will run if the first `if` statement is false.

```
function something() {
if(x == 1) {
  //do this
}
else if(x == 2) {
  //do that
}
```

So if `x == 1` was false, the next statement would be evaluated.

As for performance, the difference is way too little for you to care about. If you have many conditions you need to test, you may want to look into a [switch statement.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)